# how do i compare two ranges of data then copy and paste range that doesnt match

Tags: excel, vba

this site has been very helpful in getting my code to work and i am almost done but i am struggling in returning values of a range if a condition is not met. basically if the compared value if it doesnt match to copy the it plus the five cells to the right and paste in next available line in Output sheet range starting in H2. i have the first part of the code but am really at a loss here. i have tried my best to put the code in the right order.  do i have to repeat "For each"?

```
Dim WS1 As Worksheet: Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Increments")
Dim WS2 As Worksheet: Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

Dim LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long, WS1_Cell As Range, WS2_Cell As Range

LR1 = WS1.Range("S" & WS1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LR2 = WS2.Range("H" & WS2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each WS1_Cell In WS1.Range("S1:S" & LR1)
    For Each WS2_Cell In WS2.Range("H1:H" & LR2)
        If WS1_Cell = WS2_Cell Then
            WS2_Cell.Offset(, 5).Value = WS1_Cell.Offset(, 5).Value
        Else
            WS2_Cell.Offset(1, 1).Value = WS1_Cell.Offset(1, 1).Value
        End If
    Next WS2_Cell
Next WS1_Cell
```

for example if s2 on sheet1 doesnt equal any of the values in range h2:H100 on  sheet2 then copy range s2:x2 and paste on first available cell below last line in H on sheet2

Comment: I'd suggest using [an indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation). You don't indent code just because it looks nicer (it does) - you indent code because it makes the control flow obvious when you're looking at it.

Comment: Evaluating "doesn't equal any of the values" implies iterating al the values *before* you can take the decision to copy anything. I would suggest ditching the loop approach and copying the columns you need into in-memory arrays, then using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` to tell whether a given value exists in the array. Or populate a `Dictionary` and use its `Exists` method to know if a value exists in the dictionary - there are many, *many* examples of this on this site.

Comment: ha ha that is way beyond my beyond my skills.

Comment: Do you have to have it in a macro? What if it took about a minute to do manually?

Comment: i figured it out.
    Sub copy_not_match()
    Dim lRow As Long, lastRowE As Long

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    lRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowE = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In Range("a1:a" & lRow)
    On Error GoTo docopy
    r = Rows(Application.Match(cell.Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a1:a" & 
    lastRowE), 0)).Row
    Next
    Exit Sub

docopy:
cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Resume Next
End Sub